# shell or perl script to check group have read privileges

Tags: shell-script, files, permissions, perl, chmod

```
ls -l
drwx------   8 ws   web    1024 Apr 29  2013 abc
drwxr-xr-x   8 ws   web    1024 Oct 19  2011 def
```

I need some script to find directories like `abc` which doesn't have read/execute permissions for group `web` and give them read/execute permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` for that:

```
find / -type d -group web -exec chmod g+rx {} +
```

This is slightly inefficient as it will also set group to rw for those that already have those set. You can also have `find` check on some of the permission bits with `-perm /mode` and negate that match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner I wrote the other day for very similiar purpose. Assuming you understand `chown/chmod` ,So can adapt for your purposes. In this case, some user accounts are nested under the userX account. The problem was files uploaded by those users were still owned by `otheruser:otheruser`, So userX could not affect them, This script runs every minute to ensure userX has full control over everything uploaded by nested accounts.

Example directory structure: /home/userX/otheruser

Where /home/userX is userX home directory and /home/userX/otheruser is otheruser home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l /home/userX | grep "^d" | awk '{print$9}' | while read i; 
    do 
        chown -R $i:userX /home/userX/$i/*; 
        chmod -R 775  /home/userX/$i/*; 
    done
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `ls -ld ...`? Either way, this will break if any of your filenames contain spaces. (Many of mine do.)

Comment: As a side issue, this could be more efficiently implemented with the `inotify` subsystem. Take a look at the really useful `inotifywait` command.

Comment: Since the chown and chmod commands are recursively executed against the directory that contains the files, using the wildcard (*), file names should not be an issue. If you somehow have usernames with spaces in them, that is a different thing.